# Apollo Server resolver for whole type

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Is it possible to specify a resolver function for a whole GraphQL type, rather than for individual properties in Apollo Server v4?

I have a schema something like this:

```
type A {
    things: [Thing]
}

type B {
    things: [Thing]
}

type Thing {
    type: String!
    icon: String!
}
```

The `type` and `icon` properties are related such that writing separate resolver functions for each means repeating work. I could write a separate mapper function which returns an entire `Thing` and use that in the resolvers for `A.things` and `B.things` but that results in duplication too and potentially bugs if someone forgets to do in `C.things` later.

What I want is a resolver for the whole `Thing` type, which accepts the return value of the `things` resolvers and returns a fully formed `Thing`. I suspect this is not supported by Apollo, but just checking.

Answer (score 1):

My earlier answer approached this at the wrong level. Start at the query or the parent.

When a query or parent resolver returns `Thing` or `[Thing]` you can include as many fields as you want in the result. Only the fields that are requested and have field-level resolvers will be further resolved.

In your case `A` and `B` include a `things` field that returns `[Thing]`.

In your field resolvers for `A` and `B` you might typically do a database query to lookup all the *Things* that are related to the parent. Go ahead and define the `type` and `icon` fields for each element in that resolver but *do not* define field resolvers for `type` and `icon` under `Thing`.

If you need field resolvers for `type` and `icon` for other reasons check to see if they are part of the parent object before resolving and just return the existing values if they exist, otherwise resolve further.

You can likely reuse the `Things` resolver code in `A` and `B` by extracting it to a separate function.

Comment: I tried that but I get `"Error: \"Thing\" defined in resolvers, but has invalid value \"(parent, args, contextValue, info) => { }\". The resolver's value must be of type object."`